# How to receive messages for a correlationid from RabbitMQ using Spring AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I went through the API of RabbitTemplate. It provides only receive method which gets the message from queue. However there is no way to get a message with a particular correlation id. Can you please help me understand what I am missing here.

Currently, I am using JMS API's from ActiveMQ to receive messages using the following code which createConsumer with message selector. Looking to do the same with Spring AMQP with RabbitMQ:

```
private ObjectMessage receiveMessage(final String readQueue, final UUID correlationId, final boolean isBroadcastMessage, final int readTimeout) throws JMSException
{
    final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = this.findConnectionFactory(readQueue);
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageConsumer consumer = null;
    ObjectMessage responseMessage = null;

    try
    {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Destination destination = session.createQueue(readQueue);

        consumer = session.createConsumer(destination, "correlationId = '" + correlationId + "'");
        final Message message = consumer.receive(readTimeout);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (consumer != null)
        {
            consumer.close();
        }
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.close();
        }
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
    return responseMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `messageSelector` string in JMS; RabbitMQ/AMQP does not have an equivalant.

Instead, each consumer gets its own queue and you use a direct or topic exchange in the broker to do the routing. I suggest you take a look at [the tutorials on the rabbitmq web site](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-java.html) and [topics](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html).

If you are using the correlationId for request/reply processing, consider using the inbuilt `sendAndReceive` or `convertSendAndReceive` methods in the template. See the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply) for more information.

Comment: Can we set the timeout for the return of convertSendAndReceive? If its beyond timeout, convertSendAndReceive should return some kind of exception.

Comment: The default timeout is 5 seconds, adjust it with `setReplyTimeout(long)` (milliseconds). If it times out, you get a null return value, not an exception.